# Google Analytices.js send method

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

according to [Analytics.js send method documantation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#send) ,I have a question:

After I send a `ga('send',...)` method , does it **have** to execute a Get or Post request , or there is another implementation for this calling ?

Answer (score 2):

By default, analytics.js will automatically choose the transport method for you (based on factors like hit size, etc.). You can specify this method yourself by explicitly setting the [transport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#transport) field.

For example:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {transport: 'beacon'});
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it has to send a HTTP Post or a HTTP get.

**Reason:**

*`analytics.js`* uses the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference). The only way to communicate with the google analytics measurement protocol is with a HTTP post or a HTTP get